# Typescript push to list with connected types

Tags: typescript

Basic question about Typescript.

I have a list which connects two types with the & operator. The following shows the initialization:

```
let objects: (Object & number)[] = [];
```

How can I add values to my list? I have tried to use the push function, but I don't know how to pass the parameter correctly. For instance I have tried:

```
objects.push( {...object, 2} )
```

How should I pass the parameter?

My Object looks like:

```
object: Object = { first: string, last: string }
```

And after manipulation it should look like:

```
object: Object = { first: string, last: string, value: number }
```

I want to add the number as additional member

Comment: You want the item in the array  to be both a number and an object ?

Comment: I want to extend my object with a number

Comment: It's not clear to be what you want to do with this object after ? You want to use the array item in arithmetic operations for example ?

Comment: I extend my description. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes it is better now.

Answer (score 0):

An intersection type is the wrong approach. `Object & number` is a type that is at the same time both a `number` and an `object`. From your description of what you are trying to achieve you want an object that has an original type, and an extra `value` property:

```
let objects: ({ foo: number } & { value: number })[] = [];

let myObj = { foo: 1 }
objects.push({ ...myObj, value: 2 });
```

You can also use `object` instead of a specific type:

```
let objects: (object & { value: number })[] = [];

let myObj: object = { foo: 1 }
objects.push({ ...myObj, value: 2 });
```

But that does not really add much, since `object` does not add any properties, this will do the same thing as well:

```
let objects: ({ value: number })[] = [];

let myObj = { foo: 1 };
objects.push({ ...myObj, value: 2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to define the object as type "any" and add a property dynamically but that defeats the whole purpose of using typescript: having a strongly typed language.

My suggestion would be to just add a property to Object class in the definition.

Otherwise you can try to define a ParentObject class that contains both the object and the number value:

Create a new Object that contains both values

```
export interface ParentObject {
  object: Object;
  number: number;
}
```

Then link the object and your number value

```
let parentObject: ParentObject = {
  object: object,
  number, number
};
```

Finally push to your object list the extended parentObject

```
const objects: Object[] = [];
objects.push(parentObject);
```